# PHP when to use try/catch?

Tags: php

I was just wondering something.  In index.php, I am currently doing something like this

```
function performFtpOperation() {

    global $config;

    try {
        $ftp = new FTP\FtpClient();
        $ftp->connect($config::FTP_SERVER);
        $ftp->login($config::FTP_USER, $config::FTP_PASSWORD);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

What I was wondering is if that try catch block is needed?  Reason I question it is because my FTP class throws errors if something goes wrong.  For instance this is the connect function

```
public function connect($host, $ssl = false, $port = 21, $timeout = 90)
{
    if ($ssl) {
        $this->conn = @$this->ftp->ssl_connect($host, $port, $timeout);
    } else {
        $this->conn = @$this->ftp->connect($host, $port, $timeout);
    }
    if (!$this->conn) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

So would a try/catch be needed if errors are handled within the class?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an exception is thrown, the code following it will not be executed, and PHP will try to find the matching "catch" block.
If an exception is not caught, a fatal error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception" message.

Proper exception code should include:

Try - A function using an exception should be in a "try" block. If the exception does not trigger, the code will continue as normal. However if the exception triggers, an exception is "thrown"

Throw - This is how you trigger an exception. Each "throw" must have at least one "catch"

Catch - A "catch" block retrieves an exception and creates an object containing the exception information

Comment: Thanks for the info, one quick question.  If my login function also throws an exception, should I have both the connect and login in seperate try/catch blocks?

Answer (score 2):

The `connect` class throws exceptions that you need to catch and handle somewhere in your code. It is up to you where to handle it depending on your application design and requirements.

If you decided that you wanted to handle them in the `performFtpOperation` function, then your use of `try...catch` there is correct.

If you don't handle them in the `performFtpOperation` function, then they will bubble up to the code that calls the `performFtpOperation` function and you can catch & handle them there if you like using `try...catch` similar to how you did it here. Just remember that you need to catch them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are throwing an exception from within your FTP code, then Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try catch if you work with exeptions, otherwise you generate fatal errors and your script/site will stop work at this point, so try/catch is a part of the exeption handling.

you can inform yourself about this in the php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php